# Split a single column to 2 different column

Tags: python, dataframe, extract

Need to split the single column into 2 different columns.

I have tried few steps using regex but not able to achieve the result.

Any suggestions, please?

In the given data, we have the values of both 'A' and 'B' merged together as a single column. We need to split that.

```
Data 1

  col A
  000 5
  448 1
  469 1
  897 1

Expected
  A      B
 000     5
 448     1
 469     1
 897     1

Note: In Data 2, we have the 'B' value as null for all rows
Data 2

   col A
   524
   894
   894
   896

Expected:
   A    B
  524
  894
  894
  896
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Try str.split()?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str.extract` here:

```py
df[("A", "B")] = df["A"].str.extract(r'(\d+)(?: (\d+))?')
```

Comment: (r'(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+((?:\d+\s+\d+-\d+)?\s*)(.+)$') - It Works

Comment: @Pravin You should always include your actual data if possible.